# AutoMapper: set reference for nested property without mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to map Order class with AutoMapper:

```
class Order
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
   public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

The Product class:

```
class Product
{ 
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I have created AutoMapper maps for both Order and Product classes. In Product class I skip the Id value.

The problem is that I want to map Order.Product as a reference. I can achieve it in this way:

```
var order = new Order { Id = 1, Quantity = 5, Product = new Product { Id = 1, Name = "CPU", Price = 500 } };
var newOrder = Mapper.Map<Order, Order>(order);
newOrder.Product = order.Product; // I want to newOrder.Product reference point to the same object as order.Product
```

This approach is not ok for me, because I have to set the .Product reference manualy, I want this to be done with AutoMapper. I don't want the nested Product property to be mapped in "classic way", I just need exactly the same reference in new object.

I have tried to solve this problem with using  ResolveUsing method and IMemberValueResolver but without success, the AutoMapper still was mapping the nested Product property instead of seting its reference as same as in other Order object.

Comment: Which `AutoMapper` version you are using?

Comment: The newest: v6.0.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At first  place you should ignore `Product` property from initial mapping via mapping configuration, and then pass function, which will set `newOrder`'s `Product` property, into `AfterMap` method.

```
CreateMap<Order, Order>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Product, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
    {
        dest.Product = src.Product;
    });
```

Mapping:

```
var order = new Order { Id = 1, Quantity = 5, Product = new Product { Id = 1, Name = "CPU", Price = 500 } };
var newOrder = Mapper.Map<Order, Order>(order);

//Ouputs: true
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(newOrder.Product, order.Product));
```

Comment: Excellent! It works :) Thank you! I would give you upvote, but I have less than 15 so I can't.